# Cucumber Datatable with Hamcrest and Rest Assured and JSON Path

Tags: java, json, cucumber, jsonpath, hamcrest

I have a step similar to the following in Gherkin:

```
    And the date range options are correct
      | startDate  | endDate    | isDefault | isCurrent |
      | 2020-03-02 | 2021-03-01 | false     | false     |
      | 2019-03-02 | 2020-03-01 | false     | false     |
```

in the steps definition class, I am trying to use Rest Assured and Hamcrest to verify the date ranges in a JSON response.

```
    @And("the date range options are correct")
    public void validateDateRanges(DataTable expectedDateRanges) {
        String response = getJSONResponse();
        List<Map<String,Object>> expected = expectedDateRanges.asMaps(String.class, Object.class);
        assertThat("Date Ranges are correct", from(response).get("dateRangeOptions"), equalTo(expected));
    }
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
Expected: <[{startDate=2020-03-02, endDate=2021-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2019-03-02, endDate=2020-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2018-03-02, endDate=2019-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2018-03-02, endDate=2018-06-17, isDefault=true, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2017-03-02, endDate=2018-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2016-03-02, endDate=2017-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2015-08-18, endDate=2016-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}]>
     but: was <[{startDate=2020-03-02, endDate=2021-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2019-03-02, endDate=2020-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2018-03-02, endDate=2019-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2018-03-02, endDate=2018-06-17, isDefault=true, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2017-03-02, endDate=2018-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2016-03-02, endDate=2017-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}, {startDate=2015-08-18, endDate=2016-03-01, isDefault=false, isCurrent=false}]>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at scenarios.pagination.AccrualLog.validateDateRanges(AccrualLog.java:80)
    at ✽.the date range options are correct(file:///.../accrualLog.feature:7)
```

Considering the values are all look correct, I think this is due to the mis-match in data types - the boolean fields are being returned from the DataTable as Strings.

Is there any way to fix this, apart from using a class to represent the date ranges?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In the end, I created my own implementation of Matcher to check Cucumber DataTables:

```
public class DataTableMatcher extends BaseMatcher<Object> {

    private final List<Map<String,String>> expectedValues;

    public DataTableMatcher(Object expectedValue) {
        this.expectedValues = ((DataTable) expectedValue).asMaps();
    }

    public boolean matches(Object o) {
        List<?> actual = (List<?>) o;
        List<Map<String,String>> actualValues = actual.stream().map(this::castRow).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return expectedValues.equals(actualValues);
    }

    private Map<String,String> castRow(Object row) {
        Map<String,String> result = new HashMap<>();
        Map<?,?> cast = (Map<?,?>) row;
        for (Object column : cast.keySet()) {
            result.put(column.toString(), cast.get(column).toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("It to be right"); //TODO more helpful error message
    }
    
    public static Matcher<Object> dataTablesMatch(Object t) {
        return new DataTableMatcher(t);
    }
}
```

then I can use it like this:

```
    @And("the date range options are correct")
    public void validateDateRanges(DataTable expectedDateRanges) {
        String response = getJSONResponse();
        assertThat("Date Ranges are correct", from(response).get("dateRangeOptions"), dataTablesMatch(expectedDateRanges));
    }
```

This works. I would be very interested to hear if there are more elegant solutions, however.